PySpark dynamically extract column from array map and cast column to Struct or from_json
I have a case of an aggregated set of columns in an Array of Maps (dataset example below), for which I'm attempting to extract a set of columns by taking the Map's key and extracting the relevant column. The issue is, columns can have a wide-array of types, from just Strings to Arrays of Strings and so on.
Note: The content of the JSON can be arbitrary meaning, may contain several fields or not, and these can constantly vary, hence the need to extract the columns dynamically.
In principle, this should be simple enough even something that could be achieved via a simple CASE however, Spark forces all types returned from a CASE statement to be of the same type.
Example dataset for only four column types:
{
    "base_id": 1232321,
    "metafields": [
        {
            "key": "text_single",
            "type": "single_line_text_field",
            "value": "Single text",
            "created_at": "2024-03-16T12:14:17.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-03-16T12:14:17.000Z"
        },
        {
            "key": "text_multiple",
            "type": "list.single_line_text_field",
            "value": "[\"Multi text 1\",\"Multi text 2\"]",
            "created_at": "2024-03-16T12:14:17.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-03-16T12:14:17.000Z"
        },
        {
            "key": "datetime_single",
            "type": "date_time",
            "value": "2024-05-02T10:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2024-05-07T11:42:49.000+01:00",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-07T11:42:49.000+01:00"
        },
        {
            "key": "datetime_multiple",
            "type": "list.date_time",
            "value": "[\"2024-05-02T10:30:00Z\", \"2024-05-01T10:30:00Z\"]",
            "created_at": "2024-05-07T11:42:49.000+01:00",
            "updated_at": "2024-05-07T11:42:49.000+01:00"
        }
    ],
    "etl_executed_at": "2024-05-07T12:05:56.480+01:00"
}

Considering the case of a CASE statement, if we were to derive the object's type from the JSON itself and then contingent on the type, set the format via the from_json function:
schema_list_line: ArrayType = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("a", StringType())]))
schema_line: StructType = StructType([StructField("a", StringType())])

for col_name in ["text_single", "text_multiple"]:
  new_col: Column = spark_functions.expr(f"filter(metafields, x -> x.key = '{col_name}')")[0]["value"]
  new_col_type: Column = spark_functions.expr(f"filter(metafields, x -> x.key = '{col_name}')")[0]["type"]

  new_col = spark_functions.when(
    new_col_type == spark_functions.lit("single_line_text_field"),
     spark_functions.from_json(new_col, schema_line),
    ).when(
    new_col_type == spark_functions.lit("list.single_line_text_field"),
     spark_functions.from_json(new_col, schema_list_line),
    ).otherwise(spark_functions.from_json(new_col, schema_line))

   cols_list.append(new_col.alias(col_name))


df.select(cols_list)


This answer could serve as an example to cast columns as runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78292935/3238085
